# Specific $scope.apply(); scenario:

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angular and I've been playing around trying to learn how it works. I'm making a simple application where someone can add users through a simple html interface and store it in a database using SQLite, then they can edit or delete them.

So I was trying to understand the manual use of $scope.apply() so I did the following as to create a scenario where I would need to use it:

On a function, I store some variables in the localStorage and then I open an html manually:

```
 localStorage.setItem('idUsuario',response.records[0].idUsuario);
    localStorage.setItem('dato_Nombre',response.records[0].nombre);
    localStorage.setItem('dato_ApPat',response.records[0].apPat);
    localStorage.setItem('dato_ApMat',response.records[0].apMat);
    localStorage.setItem('dato_Direccion',response.records[0].direccion);
    localStorage.setItem('dato_Tel',response.records[0].telefono);
    localStorage.setItem('dato_email',response.records[0].correo);
    //debugger;
    location.href = "editClient.html";}
```

On the html I opened, I declared an ng-init() inside my controler which receives the stored data and assigns it to ng-model variables I declared on some text inputs:

```
 $scope.init = function () {
    $scope.idUsuario=localStorage.getItem("idUsuario");
    $scope.dato_Nombre=localStorage.getItem("dato_Nombre");
    $scope.dato_ApPat=localStorage.getItem("dato_ApPat");
    $scope.dato_ApMat=localStorage.getItem("dato_ApMat");
    $scope.dato_Tel=localStorage.getItem("dato_Tel");
    $scope.dato_Direccion=localStorage.getItem("dato_Direccion");
    $scope.dato_email=localStorage.getItem("dato_email");

    localStorage.clear();
}



<div class="list">
            <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                <span class="input-label" >Nombre</span>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Escriba su nombre" ng-model="dato_Nombre" >
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                  <span class="input-label">Apellido Paterno</span>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Escriba su apellido paterno" ng-model="dato_ApPat">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                  <span class="input-label">Apellido Materno</span>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Escriba su apellido materno" ng-model="dato_ApMat">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                  <span class="input-label">Dirección</span>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Escriba su dirección" ng-model="dato_Direccion">
            </label>
          <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
            <span class="input-label">Teléfono</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Escriba su teléfono" ng-model="dato_Tel">
          </label>
          <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                  <span class="input-label">Email</span>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Escriba su correo" ng-model="dato_email">
            </label> 
        <center>
          <button class="button button-possitive" ng-click="editarCliente()">Actualizar</button>
        </center>    
        </div>
```

So when the form loads the inputs are actually filled with the data I brought from the localStorage, then I modify that text by typing something else and call a function which returns the data in each ng-model which, like expected, has not updated to what I typed in the inputs and still has the data assigned from localStorage, hence the need to use $scope.apply().

My problem is, no matter where I try to use it, I always get an error saying  apply is already running, and I can't figure out just how to use it as to update the content of my text inputs.

Answer (score 2):

$scope.$apply fires an angular digest cycle, but since your changes are happening inside of an angular application, there is one cycle already running and processing your data, thats why you get that error, because you should not have 2 digest cycles executing at the same time. $scope.$apply is useful when some changes happen out side of the angular environment. for example when you need to integrate not friendly angular components like jquery plugins or other ui elements that process their events out side of the angular world. If you would like to update the angular app from within any of those elements events you would need to use $scope.$apply, also can happen if you choose to use setTimeout or setInterval instead of the $timeout or $interval services provided for angular, because the execution of the function would happen outside of the angular digest cycle.

```
$.ajax({
 url:'http://lslsls.com',
 method: 'get'
})
.success(function(data){
  var scope = angular.element($('#elementId')).scope();
  scope.returnedData=data;
  scope.$apply();
});
```

don't pay much attention to the jquery part but notice how in the success function the scope is retrieved and the updated, if i don't use scope.$apply() there, the values wouldn't be represented in view the scope until some other change happened and force a digest cycle